# Get a variable from href with id

Tags: php

How can I get the id as a variable from that statement in same page?

I need to capture the `#dialog` to display in a popup and can't do that if I send the id to a different page.

```
<a href="#dialog?id=<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?>" name="modal"  class="info">Link</a>
```

I've been using this to get it from the link but I need to capture it in same page. This is what i was using :

```
$img = isset($_GET['id'])
```

Comment: If you need to capture it without loading a page you'll have to use javascript. However, it's somewhat unclear specifically what you're trying to achieve. Can you clarify?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: I have an image wich is displayed from db, and i wanna send the id of that image towards popup and display another image based on that id.

Comment: I agree, it's not clear what you are asking. Could you show the code you use to send a value towards the popup and display it? Then we could help you get the value.

Comment: No. It cannot be done. You cannot access anything after the `#` character using PHP, because the server will never be allowed to see that part of the URL. The only option is to either change your URL to take away the `#` or use javascript to read it (which might send a second HTTP request to the server, including whatever is after the `#`).

Comment: You are using PHP. After the page is loaded how are you going to use PHP code whitout leaving the page??? Ajax is the only way

Comment: That's the problem :D the way i was sending the value towards the popup is the  href="#dialog?id=<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?>

Comment: #Abhi i don;t wanna leave the page i'm just tryng to send the id of photo towards the popup can it be done another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything after the Hash-Sign is evaluated by the browser only and not sent to the server. You therefore cannot access it.

Maybe you meant:

```
?id=<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?>#dialog
```

Otherwise you would have to use JS.

Comment: js is fine by me as loong as i can capture it and the display it in popup

Comment: `window.location.hash` contains the data after the hash-sign.

Comment: small problem. I am not refreshing the page so  id=<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?> is not there to be taken